# Bilateral Filter with Color

Tags: c++, opencv

I am wondering on how to calculate for parameters of bilateral filter (OpenCV)
[Bilateral Filter Parameters](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html)

- Standard deviation in the color space.
- Standard deviation in the coordinate space (in pixel terms)

I have tried to get a rough standard deviation measure of a line profile through the object that I am trying to smooth. Is this correct?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#bilateralfilter) seems that these values are rather a try and error, and not the result of some equation. Namely:

> Sigma values: For simplicity, you can set the 2 sigma values to be the same. If they are small (< 10), the filter will not have much effect, whereas if they are large (> 150), they will have a very strong effect, making the image look “cartoonish”.